# ADB on WIFI for Android 2.3.7

Tags: android, adb

I have a rooted `Samsung Galaxy Gio` running `MIUI 2.4.20`. Is there any way to use `ADB` over the network?

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you want
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [this](http://bartwell.ru/soft/android/easyremoteadb/) useful software **(Easy Remote)**, it's working with `android 2.3.7`.

Easy Remote Link: http://bartwell.ru/soft/android/easyremoteadb/

---

### Download

- APK : [Download](http://bartwell.ru/soft/android/easyremoteadb/EasyRemoteADB.apk) (318.95 KB)
- [Google Play](https://market.android.com/details?id=ru.bartwell.easyremoteadb)
- [EXE](http://bartwell.ru/soft/android/easyremoteadb/EasyRemoteADB.exe) (749.06 KB)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a terminal emulator on your device, [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1685736) tutorial enables ADB over WIFI without installing additional software.

In short, execute the following on your phone's terminal emulator:

```
su
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

You can use another port, ohter than 5555, if you want.

Find out which IP your device is using on WIFI. One way is, on phone's your terminal emulator, run the command below and search for the IP in the *wlan0* section.

```
ipaddr
```

On your computer (mine is a Linux machine), in your android SDK instalation, go to the platform-tools folder and run:

```
./adb connect <ip-address>
```

If you chose a different port run:

```
./adb connect <ip-address>:<port>
```

And you're set!

Link: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1685736